# Pyspark: Pass multiple columns in UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a User Defined Function which will take all the columns except the first one in a dataframe and do sum (or any other operation). Now the dataframe can sometimes have 3 columns or 4 columns or more. It will vary.

I know I can hard code 4 column names as pass in the UDF but in this case it will vary so I would like to know how to get it done?

Here are two examples in the first one we have two columns to add and in the second one we have three columns to add.

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If all columns you want to pass to UDF have the same data type you can use array as input parameter, for example:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array
>>> sum_cols = udf(lambda arr: sum(arr), IntegerType())
>>> spark.createDataFrame([(101, 1, 16)], ['ID', 'A', 'B']) \
...     .withColumn('Result', sum_cols(array('A', 'B'))).show()
+---+---+---+------+
| ID|  A|  B|Result|
+---+---+---+------+
|101|  1| 16|    17|
+---+---+---+------+

>>> spark.createDataFrame([(101, 1, 16, 8)], ['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C'])\
...     .withColumn('Result', sum_cols(array('A', 'B', 'C'))).show()
+---+---+---+---+------+
| ID|  A|  B|  C|Result|
+---+---+---+---+------+
|101|  1| 16|  8|    25|
+---+---+---+---+------+
```

Comment: Also works in Scala: `myUdf(array($"col1",$"col2"))`

Comment: how it can be implemented for columns with different types?

Comment: @constructor you can use `array` if sum numbers of different types also (i.e. integer and double -> both will be casted to double)

Answer (score 49):

Another simple way without Array and Struct.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

sum_cols = udf(sum, IntegerType())

a=spark.createDataFrame([(101, 1, 16)], ['ID', 'A', 'B'])
a.show()
a.withColumn('Result', sum_cols('A', 'B')).show()
```

Comment: I think you don't need to import struct.

Answer (score 25):

Use struct instead of array

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
sum_cols = udf(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], IntegerType())
a=spark.createDataFrame([(101, 1, 16)], ['ID', 'A', 'B'])
a.show()
a.withColumn('Result', sum_cols(struct('A', 'B'))).show()
```

Comment: Can you explain why one would use `struct` instead of `array`?  I'm guessing that this is to handle columns of different types?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's a late answer, but I don't like using UDFs without necessity, so:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from functools import reduce
data = [["a",1,2,5],["b",2,3,7],["c",3,4,8]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["id","v1","v2",'v3'])

calculate = reduce(lambda a, x: a+x, map(col, ["v1","v2",'v3']))

df.withColumn("Result", calculate)
#
#id v1  v2  v3  Result
#a  1   2   5   8
#b  2   3   7   12
#c  3   4   8   15
```

Here u could to use any operation which implement in `Column`.  Also if u want to write a custom `udf` with specific logic, u could use it, because `Column` provide tree execution operations. Without collecting to array and sum on it.

If compared with process as array operations, it will be bad from performance perspective, let's take a look at the physical plan, in my case and array case, in my case and `array` cased.

my case:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#355, v1#356L, v2#357L, v3#358L, ((v1#356L + v2#357L) + v3#358L) AS Result#363L]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[id#355,v1#356L,v2#357L,v3#358L]
```

array case:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#339, v1#340L, v2#341L, v3#342L, pythonUDF0#354 AS Result#348]
+- BatchEvalPython [<lambda>(array(v1#340L, v2#341L, v3#342L))], [pythonUDF0#354]
   +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[id#339,v1#340L,v2#341L,v3#342L]
```

When possible - we need to avoid using UDFs as Catalyst does not know how to optimize those

Comment: Love the coment about avoiding UDF's if possible. My understanding is that since you have to send things through the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when using UDF's it adds overhead and slows you down.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to type out all your column names and would rather just dump all the columns into your UDF, you'll need to wrap a list comprehension within a struct.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, udf
sum_udf = udf(lambda x: sum(x[1:]))
df_sum = df.withColumn("result", sum_udf(struct([df[col] for col in df.columns])))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I tried and seemed to work:

```
colsToSum = df.columns[1:]
df_sum = df.withColumn("rowSum", sum([df[col] for col in colsToSum]))
```

Comment: This only works because you're not calling a UDF.  Otherwise, you'll need to wrap this list comprehension within a struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
            udf_ = spark.udf.register("udf_",self.funct)
            print("registered udf................:",udf_)
            df = df.withColumn('result',udf_(struct([df[col] for col in df.columns]))) 
            print("after df call")
```

where self.funct is defined in another class and I am trying to register this function using spark.udf.register and call this function from df.withColumn and returning as result  is not working ..

Output:
registered udf................: <function function.funct at 0x7f8ee4c5bf28>
after df call

but in real this is not entering into the funct function of the function class.

function class as follows
class function():
def **init**:
def funct(self,df):
print("inside funct function")
return F.col(S)*F.col(S)

S column is part of df data frame and int

Answer (score 0):

These days you no longer need `struct`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf('integer')
def my_sum(*args):
  return sum(args)

df = spark.createDataFrame([(101, 1, 16)], ['ID', 'A', 'B'])

display(df.withColumn('total', my_sum(*df.columns[1:])))
```