# Rowwise manipulation of a DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If have a DataFrame and want to do some manipulation of the data in a function depending on the values of the row.

```
my_udf(row):
    threshold = 10
        if row.val_x > threshold
        row.val_x = another_function(row.val_x)
        row.val_y = another_function(row.val_y)
        return row
    else:
        return row
```

Does anyone know how to apply my udf to the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, udf parameters are column names. Your example might be rewrote like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def change_val_x(val_x):
    threshold = 10
    if val_x > threshold:
        return another_function(val_x)
    else:
        return val_x

def change_val_y(arr):
    threshold = 10
    # arr[0] -> val_x, arr[0] -> val_y 
    if arr[0] > threshold:
        return another_function(arr[1])
    else:
        return val_y

change_val_x_udf = udf(change_val_x, IntegerType())
change_val_y_udf = udf(change_val_y, IntegerType())

# apply these functions to your dataframe
df = df.withColumn('val_y', change_val_y_udf(array('val_x', 'val_y')))\
       .withColumn('val_x', change_val_x_udf('val_x'))
```

To modify val_x column, a simple udf is enough but for val_y you need val_y and val_x columns values, the solution is to use an `array`. Note that this code is not tested...

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540169/pyspark-pass-multiple-columns-in-udf) to apply udf on multiple columns.

Comment: it's `.withColumn('val_y', change_val_y_udf(array('val_x', 'val_y')))` not `.withColumn('val_y', change_val_x_udf(array('val_x', 'val_y')))`

Comment: Also you might have changed `val_x` value before using it in in `change_val_y_udf `.

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to use UDFs if you can use pyspark functions, if you can't translate `another_function` into pyspark functions you can do this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

def another_function(val):
    ...

another_function_udf = psf.udf(another_function, [outputType()])
```

where `outputType()` is the pyspark type corresponding to the output of `another_function` (`IntegerType()`, `StringType()`...)

```py
def apply_another_function(val):
    return psf.when(df.val_x > threshold, another_function_udf(val)).otherwise(val)

df = df.withColumn('val_y', apply_another_function(df.val_y))\
       .withColumn('val_x', apply_another_function(df.val_x))
```