# pyspark conditions on multiple columns and returning new column

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using spark 2.1 and scripting is pyspark. Please help me with this as I am stuck up here .

Problem statement: To create new columns based on conditions on multiple columns

Input `dataframe` is below

```
FLG1 FLG2 FLG3

T     F     T

F     T     T

T     T     F
```

Now I need to create one new column as FLG and my conditions would be like if `FLG1==T&&(FLG2==F||FLG2==T)` my `FLG` has to be `T` else `F`

Considered above `dataframe` as `DF`

below is my code snippet which was tried

```
DF.withColumn("FLG",DF.select(when(FLG1=='T' and (FLG2=='F' or FLG2=='T','F').otherwise('T'))).show()
```

Didn't work I was getting name when is not defined

Please help me in crossing this hurdle

Comment: `and` and `or` will not work in pyspark - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, it should work

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit
DF.withColumn("FLG", when((col("FLG1")=='T') & ((col("FLG2")=='F') | (col("FLG2")=='T')),lit('F')).otherwise(lit('T'))).show()
```

Comment: Thans for quick reply Ramesh. Getting unsupported operand type for |: 'str' and 'Dataframe' what could be the issue

Comment: my pleasure @user3292373 :) and thanks for upvote and acceptance

Comment: Ramesh one more help if the columns are increasing and conditions are increasing now . I need to create an udf that generates one column in that udf I need to give conditions on the columns that I pass as parameter how do I do it .On passed parameters columns the conditions are perfrmed and returned as true or false . How do I do it

Comment: you can get ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540169/pyspark-pass-multiple-columns-in-udf