# Adding a Column in DataFrame from another column of same dataFrame Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe `df`, like following:

```
+---+----+---+
| id|name|  c|
+---+----+---+
|  1|   a|  5|
|  2|   b|  4|
|  3|   c|  2|
|  4|   d|  3|
|  5|   e|  1|
+---+----+---+
```

I want to add a column `match_name` that have value from the `name` column where `id == c`

Is it possible to do it with function `withColumn()`?

Currently i have to create two dataframes and then perform join.
Which is inefficient on large dataset.

Expected Output:

```
+---+----+---+----------+
| id|name|  c|match_name|
+---+----+---+----------+
|  1|   a|  5|         e|
|  2|   b|  4|         d|
|  3|   c|  2|         b|
|  4|   d|  3|         c|
|  5|   e|  1|         a|
+---+----+---+----------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark conditions on multiple columns and returning new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845238/pyspark-conditions-on-multiple-columns-and-returning-new-column)

Comment: What is `c`?? Where is the original `match` column??

Comment: `c` and `match` are the same i change it for simplicity

Comment: No answers then?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, with [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

condition = col("id") == col("match")
result = df.withColumn("match_name", when(condition, col("name"))

result.show()

id name match match_name
1  a    3     null
2  b    2     b
3  c    5     null
4  d    4     d
5  e    1     null
```

You may also use [`otherwise`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise) to provide a different value if the condition is not met.

Comment: ... faster by some seconds (+1)... :)

Comment: ` from pyspark.sql import functions as func
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'a', 5), (2, 'b', 4), (3, 'c', 2), (4, 'd', 3), (5, 'e', 1)], ['id', 'name', 'c'])
condition = func.col("id") == func.col("c")
result = df.withColumn("match_name", func.when(condition, func.col("name")))

result.show()`

Comment: Sir i want to take name of the column where id is `3` and add it across the row having id `1`

Comment: @JugrajSingh 1) please, do not put long code snippets in the comments - they are unreadable 2) of course you do, because in these (new) data the condition is nowhere matched! I have confirmed that the solution with the data you provided **originally** in your post is indeed as shown and as expected...

Comment: agreed and apologies but my requirement is different. it is to fill all rows with ther possible match_name like join does.

Comment: please keep in mind the value of the column come from a different row in the same dataset

Comment: @JugrajSingh then describe it accurately, including the desired output!! The answer is **exactly** what you have asked for