# Pyspark udf returning one column on condition definitions accepting several columns as input

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using spark 2.1 and usage is pyscripting

Problem Statement: Have an scenario where there is an need to pass multiple columns as input and return one column as output below is my input dataframe of 3 columns

a b c

S S S

S NS NS

S NS S

S S NS

NS S NS

my output has to be as below

a b c d

S S S S

S NS NS NS

S NS S S

S S NS NS

NS S NS NS

I am trying to register an UDF to pass these 3 columns[a,b,c] as input and return d column as output here a,b,c,d are the column names

I am finding difficult to get the output below is the syntax used

```
def return_string(x):
      if [x.a=='s' & x.b=='S' & x.c=='s']
          return 'S'
      else if[x.a=='s' & x.b=='NS' & x.c=='s']
          return 'S'
      else if[x.a=='s' & x.b=='S' & x.c=='NS']
          return 'NS;

func= udf(returnstring,types.StringType())
```

Can anyone please help me in completing this logic.

Comment: Are all three columns important? For this sample output it seems to only depend on C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark: Pass multiple columns in UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540169/pyspark-pass-multiple-columns-in-udf)

Comment: Yes all three are important as missed one more logic if x.a=='NS' & x.b=='S' | x.c=='NS'  return 'NS' but what you have mentioned is right for this sample output other columns can alone be considered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was trying to do it using the built-in [`withColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn) and [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit

df.withColumn('d', when(
     ((col('A') == 'S') & (col('B') == 'S') & (col('C')=='S'))
   | ((col('A') == 'S') & (col('B') == 'NS') & (col('C')=='S'))
 , lit('S')
 ).otherwise(lit('NS'))
).show()
```

This is also assuming that the two values are mutually exclusive (hence the `otherwise`)

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
@udf
def return_string(a, b, c):
    if a == 's' and b == 'S' and c == 's':
        return 'S'
    if a == 's' and b == 'NS' and c == 's':
        return 'S'
    if a == 's' and b == 'S' and c == 'NS':
        return 'NS'

df = sc.parallelize([('s', 'S', 'NS'), ('?', '?', '?')]).toDF(['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.withColumn('result', return_string('a', 'b', 'c')).show()
## +---+---+---+------+
## |  a|  b|  c|result|
## +---+---+---+------+
## |  s|  S| NS|    NS|
## |  ?|  ?|  ?|  null|
## +---+---+---+------+
```

- All arguments should be listed (unless you pass data as `struct`).
- You should use `and` not `&` (you evaluate logical expressions not SQL expressions).
- Conditions should be expressions not lists (non-empty list are always truthy).

Personally I'd skip all the `ifs` and use simple `dict`:

```
@udf
def return_string(a, b, c):
    mapping = {
        ('s', 'S', 's'): 'S',
        ('s', 'NS' 's'): 'S',
        ('s', 'S', 'NS'): 'NS',
    }
    return mapping.get((a, b, c))
```

Adjust conditions according to your requirements.

Overall you should prefer SQL expressions as shown in [the excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45848299/8371915) provided by Steven Laan (you can chain multiple conditions with `when(..., ...).when(..., ...)`).