# PySpark UDF with multiple arguments returns null

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark Dataframe with two columns (`A`, `B`, whose type is `double`) whose values are either `0.0` or `1.0`.
I am trying to add a new column, which is the sum of those two.
I followed examples in [Pyspark: Pass multiple columns in UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540169/pyspark-pass-multiple-columns-in-udf)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType
sum_cols = F.udf(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], IntegerType())
df_with_sum = df.withColumn('SUM_COL',sum_cols(F.array('A','B')))
df_with_sum.select(['SUM_COL']).toPandas()
```

This shows a Series of `NULL`s instead of the results I expect.

I tried any of the following to see if there's an issue with data types

```py
sum_cols = F.udf(lambda x: x[0], IntegerType())
sum_cols = F.udf(lambda x: int(x[0]), IntegerType())
```

still getting Nulls.

I tried removing the array:

```py
sum_cols = F.udf(lambda x: x, IntegerType())
df_with_sum = df.withColumn('SUM_COL',sum_cols(df.A))
```

This works fine and shows `0/1`

I tried removing the UDF, but leaving the array:

```py
df_with_sum = df.withColumn('SUM_COL', F.array('A','B'))
```

This works fine and shows a series of arrays of `[0.0/1.0, 0.0/1.0]`

So, array works fine, UDF works fine, it is just when I try to pass an array to UDF that things break down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are the datatypes of columns A and B? can you check that and update the question?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes, updated! The type is double.

Comment: how 0/1 is double? is it 0/1 or 0.1?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan it is 0.0 or 1.0 for A and B, the output should be 0, 1 or 2 (depending on what the operation is, I showed several examples -  in one of them I call int() within the UDF,  and the UDF return is IntegerType, in another I don't use a UDF at all, so it is 0.0 or 1.0)

Comment: I am not understanding the form `0.0/1.0` it should be 0.0 if the datatype is double. if the value is `0.0/1.0` then the datatype should be StringType. isn't it so?

Comment: instead of lambda if we need to do in different  function how can I do  "

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are trying to return a double in a function that is supposed to output an integer, which does not fit, and pyspark by default silently resorts to `NULL` when a casting fails:

```
df_with_doubles = spark.createDataFrame([(1.0,1.0), (2.0,2.0)], ['A', 'B'])
sum_cols = F.udf(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], IntegerType())
df_with_sum = df_with_double.withColumn('SUM_COL',sum_cols(F.array('A','B')))
df_with_sum.select(['SUM_COL']).toPandas()
```

You get:

```
  SUM_COL
0    None
1    None
```

However, if you do:

```
df_with_integers = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1), (2,2)], ['A', 'B'])
sum_cols = F.udf(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], IntegerType())
df_with_sum = df_with_integers.withColumn('SUM_COL',sum_cols(F.array('A','B')))
df_with_sum.select(['SUM_COL']).toPandas()
```

You get:

```
   SUM_COL
0        2
1        4
```

So, either cast your columns to `IntegerType` beforehand (or cast them in the UDF), or change the return type of the UDF to `DoubleType`.

Comment: Is there any way to get it to show logs or any hint that the problem is a casting failure vs. something else?